# Convert char to number

Tags: numbers, lisp, char

I'm in the process of reading a flat file - to use the characters read I want to convert them into numbers. I wrote a little function that converts a string to a vector:

```
(defun string-to-vec (strng)
  (setf strng (remove #\Space strng)) 
    (let ((vec (make-array (length strng))))
      (dotimes (i (length strng) vec)
        (setf (svref vec i) (char strng i)))))
```

However this returns a vector with character entries. Short of using `char-code` to convert unit number chars to numbers in a function, is there a simple way to read numbers as numbers from a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Rainer's answer, let me mention [`read-from-string`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_fro.htm) (note that Rainer's code is more efficient than repeated application of `read-from-string` because it only creates a stream once) and [`parse-integer`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_parse_.htm) (alas, there is no `parse-float`).

Note that if you are reading a CSV file, you should probably use an off-the-shelf library instead of writing your own.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll especially look into `parse-integer`.

Comment: Well, there is `parse-float` in libraries. In fact, multiple ones, like this: https://github.com/vseloved/arnesi/blob/master/src/numbers.lisp#L30

Comment: I usually recommend the library `parse-number`.

Answer (score 2):

Above is shorter:

```
? (map 'vector #'identity (remove #\Space "123"))
#(#\1 #\2 #\3)
```

You can convert a string:

```
(defun string-to-vector-of-numbers (string)
  (coerce 
   (with-input-from-string (s string)
     (loop with end = '#:end
           for n = (read s nil end)
           until (eql n end)
           unless (numberp n) do (error "Input ~a is not a number." n)
           collect n))
   'vector))
```

But it would be easier to read the numbers directly form the file. Use `READ`, which can read numbers.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll examine this code carefully. Thanks for the READ tip also. I'll have to make sure I write code to check for a new line though, as `read-line` did that for me- I'll use a `read-line` to check the elements in a line first then go ahead with `read`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `read`-like functions are affected by reader macros.

Pick an example:

```
* (defvar *foo* 'bar)

*FOO*
* (read-from-string "#.(setq *foo* 'baz)")

BAZ
19
* *foo*

BAZ
```

As you can see `read-from-string` can implicitly set a variable. You can disable the `#.` reader macro by setting `*read-eval*` to `nil` but anyway if you have only integers on the input then consider using [`parse-integer`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_parse_.htm) instead.